# MS SQL + Python (IronPython) timing out

Tags: python, sql-server, ironpython, pymssql

I'm querying MS SQL using python using the source code from http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Accessing_SQL_Server:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
from System.Data import *

TheConnection = SqlClient.SqlConnection
("server=yourserver;database=News;uid=sa;password=password;timeout=0")
TheConnection.Open()

MyAction = SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select Headline from News", TheConnection)
MyReader = MyAction.ExecuteReader()

while MyReader.Read():
    print MyReader[0]

MyReader.Close()
TheConnection.Close()
```

I just added `timeout=0`, but still I got :

```
EnvironmentError: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout 
expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation 
or the server is not responding.
```

I tried it with `timeout=1000000`, but still got the same error.

If I run the same SQL in the same machine using the MSSQL Client, it's totally fine. Do you know how to avoid this timeout exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing the CommandTimeout property on the SqlCommand as described here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx

The timeout value in the connection string only controls the timeout for the initial connection to the database. That will not help if your SQL query takes a long time to execute so you need to use CommandTimeout instead.